# Реализуйте методы класса для ввода данных, вывода данных, реализуйте доступ к отдельным полям через методы класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Задача: Реализуйте класс «Человек». Необходимо хранить в полях класса: ФИО, дату рождения, контактный телефон, город, страну, домашний адрес. Реализуйте методы класса для ввода данных, вывода данных, реализуйте доступ к  отдельным полям через методы класса

При отработке последнего принта получаю:

> None
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

```
class Homo():
    """метод введення даних"""

    def __init__(self, name_surname_patronymic, bithtday, telephone_num, city, country, adress):
        self.name_surname_patronymic = name_surname_patronymic
        self._bithtday = bithtday
        self._telephone_num = telephone_num
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
        self._adress = adress

    def print_pablic_inf(self):
        show_pablic_inf = str(self.name_surname_patronymic) + self.city + " " + self.country
        return (self.name_surname_patronymic, self.city, self.country)

    def print_privat_inf(self):
        show_privat_inf = str(self.name_surname_patronymic) + " " + self._bithtday + " " + self._telephone_num \
                          + " " + self.city + " " + self.country + " " + self._adress
        return (
        self.name_surname_patronymic, self._bithtday, self._telephone_num, self.city, self.country, self._adress)

    def print_pablic_inf_1(self):
        return self.print_privat_inf()

homo_sapiens = Homo(
    "Ке́нни Макко́рмик",
    "24 of april",
    "0937225256",
    "Саус-парк",
    "USA",
    "South Park"
)

# print(homo_sapiens.print_pablic_inf())
print(homo_sapiens.print_pablic_inf_1())
```

Comment: Я вам отформатировал код, в следующий раз сделайте это сами ;)

Comment: В конструкторе у вас `self._bithtdaybithtday = bithtday`, а обращаетесь в другом методе к `self._bithtday`

Comment: исправила и  self._bithtday = bithtday и         self._telephone_num = telephone_num. Теперь результат второго принта - None

Comment: Я не получил `None`, а `('Ке́нни Макко́рмик', '24 of april', '0937225256', 'Саус-парк', 'USA', 'South Park')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я отметил для вас, где надо внести исправления:

```
class Homo():
    """метод введення даних"""
    def __init__(self, name_surname_patronymic, bithtday, telephone_num, city, country, adress):
        self.name_surname_patronymic = name_surname_patronymic
        
#        self._bithtdaybithtday = bithtday
        self._bithtday = bithtday
        
#        self._telephone_numtelephone_num = telephone_num
        self._telephone_num = telephone_num
        
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
        self._adress = adress

    def print_pablic_inf(self): 
        show_pablic_inf = str(self.name_surname_patronymic) + self.city + " " + self.country
        return (self.name_surname_patronymic, self.city, self.country)

    def print_privat_inf(self):
        show_privat_inf = str(self.name_surname_patronymic) + " " + self._bithtday + " " + self._telephone_num \
                          + " " + self.city + " " + self.country + " " + self._adress
        return (self.name_surname_patronymic, self._bithtday, self._telephone_num, self.city, self.country, self._adress)

    def print_pablic_inf_1(self):
#        self.print_privat_inf()
        return self.print_privat_inf()


homo_sapiens = Homo(
    "Ке́нни Макко́рмик", 
    "24 of april", 
    "0937225256", 
    "Саус-парк", 
    "USA", 
    "South Park"
)

print(homo_sapiens.print_pablic_inf())
print(homo_sapiens.print_pablic_inf_1())
```

Comment: поправила, всеравно получаю

None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @Julia  вы обратили внимание, что я заменил строку `self.print_privat_inf()` на `return self.print_privat_inf()` ?

Comment: Да, и код в вопросе обновила

Comment: Переписала, а не скопировала. Получилось. Спасибо

Comment: @Julia   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: отметила сразу, но, я тут новенькая, поэтому: 
Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: @Julia sorry, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Вы пытались проголосовать за то, что мой ответ полезен вам., а я вам напоминаю чтобы сделали пометку о том, что мой ответ правильный. Т.е. правильный и полезный - это разные понятия.

Comment: спасибо, разобралась. отметила